# Return Upper Case Column Names from Sequelize Raw MSSQL Query

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'd like to have Sequelize MSSQL raw queries return column names as upper case object attributes.  I'm not seeing a config for this in the documentation.

Example:

```
sequelize.query(sql, opts).then((results) => {
  console.log(results[0]);
});
```

What I get:
`// { foo: "bar", baz_pop: "boop" }`

What I need:
`// { FOO: "bar", BAZ_POP: "boop" }`

Comment: please share the `sql` query

Comment: Thank you @SamuelG!  I took another look at the function that composes the query and the columns specified are lower case!
Some of these queries are shared with an Oracle implementation that does not have this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any appropriate SQL when executing `query()` so you can use [UPPER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/upper-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Example:

```
await sequelize.query("SELECT UPPER(name) As name FROM departments", { type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT });
```

Yields the same SQL:

```
SELECT UPPER(name) AS name FROM departments
```

Results:

```
[ { name: 'DEPT 1' } ]
```

Comment: This returns uppercase values. The column names (ex: `name`) are still lowercase.